# Как изменить значение select при изменении другого select

Tags: javascript, java, html, запрос

Есть jsp-страница, на нее я передаю в select список стран, у каждой страны есть список городов, который есть в моей БД отдельной таблицей. Как сделать чтобы при выборе и смене страны - спосок городов обновлялся и становился невыбраным?

Правильным решением будет подгружать именно список стран из БД или это нормально захардкодить все овер 300стран в html код?

Я js не знаю, но думаю, что если без него никак, то с кодом разберусь. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: без js никак не получится. если не делать end-point на стороне сервера, то придется добавить все страны на страницу

Comment: А с js можете подсказать как это делается? я так понял, что мне нужно повесить слушатель onchange на изминение первого селекта, и при изминение делать асинхронный запрос, но как это делать не имею ни малейшого понятия (я про асинхронный запрос).

Comment: а как написать обработку запроса на стороне сервера знаете?

Comment: Обычные запросы я писал (которые делаются при нажатии на кнопку submit), если этот ничем не отличается - то да.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такой вариант с использованием jQuery

```
$("#countries").change(function () {
    $.getJSON("/cities", null, function (data) {
        $("#cities option").remove();
        $.each(data.cities, function (index, item) {
            $("#cities").append(
                $("<option></option>").text(item.name).val(item.id)
            )
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: поначалу, когда я посмотрел - мне это показалось аброй кадаброй, но потом, потом, однако я, вродебы увидил в этом логику) спасибо, попробую с Вашим кодом. Только у меня возвращать будет не JSON, а джавовский ArrayList. Это как то поменяет ситуацию?

Comment: поменяет - все перестанет работать. настройте правильно конвертацию объектов. в основном веб использует JSON. если ответ подходит, то принимайте его.

Comment: ок, разберусь (просто опыта пока что мало). Спасибо!

Comment: вы какой фреймворк используете? что исправить в ответе?

Comment: я на голых сервлетах далею. ничего исправлять не нужно. спасибо!

Comment: Рекомендую перейти на spring. Тогда будет проще. Например, он из коробки умеет переделывать в json и обратно. Если ответ устраивает - его надо принять. Появится зелёная галочка рядом.

Comment: я по условиям задания не могу спрингом пользоваться, но я там разберусь. за js спасибо.